# How does tp_call slot of the class' metaclass invokes the actual __init__ method of the class, when initializing an instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

First I'm gonna try to explain a few things and be more explicit so that I can point out what my real problem is.

Let's say we have defined a class and make an instance of a class:

```
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass  

mycls = Myclass()
```

When we disassemble this:

```
              0 LOAD_BUILD_CLASS
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object Myclass at 0x0000011C7CAA1BB0, file "sample.py", line 1>)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Myclass')
              6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Myclass')
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             12 STORE_NAME               0 (Myclass)

             14 LOAD_NAME                0 (Myclass)
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             18 STORE_NAME               1 (mycls)
             20 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

*CPython process:*

To make it short the byte offset 0 to 12, the CALL_FUNCTION opcode will call the `builtin__build_class__` function and pop two arguments in the stack. Inside that function, it will call the metaclass `tp_call` slot member, in our case the `PyType_Type` or `type` in python. `tp_call` points to `type_call` function in `C` language, which invokes the `tp_new` slot of the metaclass and eventually it will call the `tp_init`.

And also this is the disassembly of `Myclass`:

```
Disassembly of <code object Myclass at 0x00000222820B1BB0, file "sample.py", line 1>:
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (__name__)
              2 STORE_NAME               1 (__module__)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Myclass')
              6 STORE_NAME               2 (__qualname__)

  2           8 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object __init__ at 0x00000222820B1B00, file "sample.py", line 2>)
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 ('Myclass.__init__')
             12 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             14 STORE_NAME               3 (__init__)
             16 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

I forgot to mention that during the execution of `__build_class__` function before we call the metaclass' `tp_call` slot, the namepace of the class is prepared by the `__prepare__` method. The bytecode instructions of the `Myclass` (above) will be evaluated by calling `PyEval_EvalCodeEx` up to  `_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault`. We can see in the bytecode instructions that we store the `__init__` method inside the namespace or the dictionary of the class.

```
cell = PyEval_EvalCodeEx(PyFunction_GET_CODE(func), PyFunction_GET_GLOBALS(func), ns,
                             NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL,
                             PyFunction_GET_CLOSURE(func));
```

When we instantiate a class in python we explicitly have to call the class itself. The way python interprets this, is to call the `tp_call` slot of the metaclass of the class, in our case the `PyType_Type`, and eventually calls the `tp_new` and followed by `tp_init`.

In addition when the class is being created by the `tp_new` slot, to be precise the `tp_new` slot of `PyType_Type` points to `type_new` function. Inside that function, it calls the `fixup_slot_dispatchers` which stores the proper functions in the type slot's offset.

*tp_new and tp_init slotdef instance*

```
 FLSLOT("__init__", tp_init, slot_tp_init, (wrapperfunc)(void(*)(void))wrap_init,
           "__init__($self, /, *args, **kwargs)\n--\n\n"
           "Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.",
           PyWrapperFlag_KEYWORDS)

 TPSLOT("__new__", tp_new, slot_tp_new, NULL,
           "__new__(type, /, *args, **kwargs)\n--\n\n"
           "Create and return new object.  See help(type) for accurate signature."),
```

So the `Myclass`' tp_new points to slot_tp_new and tp_init will points to slot_tp_init.

*Definition of slot_tp_new*

```
static PyObject *
slot_tp_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    PyThreadState *tstate = _PyThreadState_GET();
    PyObject *func, *result;

    func = _PyObject_GetAttrId((PyObject *)type, &PyId___new__);
    if (func == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    result = _PyObject_Call_Prepend(tstate, func, (PyObject *)type, args, kwds);
    Py_DECREF(func);
    return result;
}
```

*Definition of slot_tp_init*

```
static int
slot_tp_init(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    PyThreadState *tstate = _PyThreadState_GET();

    _Py_IDENTIFIER(__init__);
    int unbound;
    PyObject *meth = lookup_method(self, &PyId___init__, &unbound);
    if (meth == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    PyObject *res;
    if (unbound) {
        res = _PyObject_Call_Prepend(tstate, meth, self, args, kwds);
    }
    else {
        res = _PyObject_Call(tstate, meth, args, kwds);
    }
    Py_DECREF(meth);
    if (res == NULL)
        return -1;
    if (res != Py_None) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "__init__() should return None, not '%.200s'",
                     Py_TYPE(res)->tp_name);
        Py_DECREF(res);
        return -1;
    }
    Py_DECREF(res);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is why the `slot_tp_init` function looks up for the **init** method definition through its's MRO? Because when you walk through in `lookup_method(self, &PyId___init__, &unbound)` you will end up calling the `_PyType_Lookup` function which looks for a name through the MRO.

Or is there any different way that python invokes the actual `__init__` method inside the class?

*Feel free to correct my perception and understanding with regard to this topic.*

Comment: "My question is why the `slot_tp_init` function looks up for the `__init__` method definition through its's MRO?" - what were you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting that, `slot_tp_init` function should lookup for `__init__` attribute of  the class, just like what `slot_tp_new` does.

Comment: `__new__` is the odd one out there. They kind of got lazy with that one - they *should* have done an MRO search and then handled descriptors manually. The direct MRO search is intended to bypass `__getattr__`/`__getattribute__` overrides, and make sure the method is found in a class dict instead of in an instance dict or metaclass dict.